# Как управлять загрузкой процессора на php?

Tags: php, производительность, процессор

Наверняка вы сталкивались с задачей когда писали парсеры больших файлов или когда писали высоконагруженные скрипты - сталкивались с тем что процессор нагружен на 100% и если это происходит на сервере, то другие пользователи не могут получить доступ к ресурсам - с этой проблемой столкнулся и я. только через год после возникновения проблемы удалось на мой взгляд найти удовлетворительное решение.

Задача заключается собственно вот в чем: нагрузка на процессор не должна превышать n % (n вы задаете сами). Актуально это только для высоконагруженных процессов имеется ввиду то, что сервак у вас выступает в качестве вычислительной машины.

Если же вы знаете способы не нагружать процессор на 100% настройками сервера - выложите сюда ответы. Если будет необходимо отредактировать вопрос или ответ - я это сделаю - только укажите что редактировать в комментарии.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/106381/

Comment: 20 — наименьший приоритет, но это, с другой стороны, самые вежливые процессы. У меня и так все процессы с этим приоритетом - понижать некуда

Comment: можно другим повысить. Если всем процессам понизить приоритет, это не уберет нагрузку на процессор. Загрузка 100% в случае линукс сервера ни о чем не говорит. Если админ пишет об этом - выгоняйте его. Спрашивать нужно о load average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответом на этот вопрос послужила [статья](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/how-to-calculate-cpu-usage-of-a-php-script/) о том как замерять нагруженность процессора, исходя из приведенных функций - вот как удалось решить проблему контроля нагрузки на процессор

```
function onRequestStart() {
        $dat = getrusage();
        define('PHP_TUSAGE', microtime(true));
        define('PHP_RUSAGE', $dat["ru_utime.tv_sec"]*1e6+$dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"]);
    }
     
    function getCpuUsage() {
        $dat = getrusage();
        $dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"] = ($dat["ru_utime.tv_sec"]*1e6 + $dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"]) - PHP_RUSAGE;
        $time = (microtime(true) - PHP_TUSAGE) * 1000000;
     
        // cpu per request
        if($time > 0) {
            $cpu = sprintf("%01.2f", ($dat["ru_utime.tv_usec"] / $time) * 100);
        } else {
            $cpu = '0.00';
        }
     
        return $cpu;
    }
    $start=time();
    onRequestStart();//запускается в начале скрипта
    $a=1000000;
    $size=10000000;
    $counter=0;
    $timeout=100000;
    for($i=0;$i<=$size;$i++){
        $a+=100;
        if(getCpuUsage()>80){//если загрузка процессора достигла 80% погружаем процесс на одну сотую секунды в сон
            usleep($timeout);
            ++$counter;
        }
    }
    $end=time()-$start;
    echo 'Спал '.$timeout*$counter/1000000 .' секунд; ушло времени '.$end.' c';
    gc_disable(); //чистка мусора из памяти сервера
```

вот результаты теста

```
$timeout=1000000; //Спал 8 секунд; ушло времени 48 c - результатов не дало - процессор загружался на 100%
$timeout=100000; //Спал 7.5 секунд; ушло времени 46 c
$timeout=10000; //Спал 7.95 секунд; ушло времени 48 c
$timeout=1000;  //Спал 7.888 секунд; ушло времени 49 c
$timeout=100;   //Спал 5.3308 секунд; ушло времени 50 c
$timeout=10;    //Спал 1.18124 секунд; ушло времени 47 c
$timeout=1;     //Спал 0.152863 секунд; ушло времени 50 c
```

во всех случаях, кроме первого, нагрузка на процессор не превышала 85% по результатам htop - возможно это связано с тем, что htop обновляется раз в секунду

также я заметил что с уменьшением времени для сна - увеличивается количество засыпаний с 3500 до 250 000 при том что всего циклов 10 000 000